# How to modify the `aws-auth` Config Map after creating EKS with Pulumi?

Tags: amazon-eks, pulumi, infrastructure-as-code

**Context**

I provision an EKS with additional IAM resources (Role, Policy, Policy Attachment) that define admin access to the cluster. If I understood Pulumi docs correctly, I then need to attach the Role ARN created to the `aws-auth` Config Map. This Config Map is bootstrapped when EKS gets created. I would like to be able to either update it with the role, or delete it once it is bootstrapped by Amazon, and then recreate it.

The furthers I've gone with it was to try and create that Config Map with Pulumi, and put the cluster as a dependency. However, I occasionally see that Pulumi tries to create it before the cluster is up and fails. Re-running `pulumi up` again then fails to create that map again, because Amazon had created one already. My current solution is to wait until the Amazon-managed `aws-auth` Config Map gets created, delete it, and then attempt to create my own with Pulumi.

**Questions**

1. Is there a much simpler solution to this problem?
2. Is there any Pulumi-native variable I could read to discover if the current run is `preview`? During `preview`, I don't want to read the Config Map (because the cluster doesn't exist yet).

Thanks in adv

Answer (score -1):

The `aws-auth` configmap is created after your cluster is created, but before your nodes are attached.

This means that you can define a cluster without any nodes, and the `aws-auth` configmap doesn't exist:

```js
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";
import * as awsx from "@pulumi/awsx";

const vpc = awsx.ec2.Vpc.getDefault();

const role = new aws.iam.Role("eks", {
    assumeRolePolicy: aws.iam.assumeRolePolicyForPrincipal({ Service: "eks.amazonaws.com" }),
})

new aws.iam.RolePolicyAttachment("eks-service-policy", {
    role: role.id,
    policyArn: "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy"
})

new aws.iam.RolePolicyAttachment("eks-cluster-policy", {
    role: role.id,
    policyArn: "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy",
})

const cluster = new aws.eks.Cluster("eks", {
    roleArn: role.arn,
    vpcConfig: {
        publicAccessCidrs: [ "0.0.0.0/0" ],
        subnetIds: vpc.publicSubnetIds, 
    }
})
```

If you create the `aws-auth` configmap inside an apply once, the cluster is created, you can create your own `aws-auth` configmap before it's automatically generated:

```js
const auth = cluster.endpoint.apply(endpoint => 
    new k8s.core.v1.ConfigMap("aws-auth", {
        metadata: {
            name: "aws-auth"
        }
    }))
```

You'd then create the nodes using a `dependsOn` on the `auth` constant when defining your nodes.

The problem with this is that creating resources inside an `apply` with Pulumi can mean the `preview` operation is not accurate. With all that in mind, I'd recommend just using the `pulumi-eks` package, which allows you to set the roleMappings as part of the cluster creation: https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/eks/api-docs/cluster/#rolemappings_nodejs